# Understanding the range of $f(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, rational-functions

Let's take the function $$f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}.$$

> My question is, why is the range of the function is all real numbers?

Because doesn't the fact that the denominator must be $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^{2}}$ and that the numerator must be $x$ limit the amount of values the function can produce? Because for every $x$, only one denominator value is possible. Doesn't this limit the output of this function, therefore preventing it from producing all real numbers? And furthermore, can you prove to me that the $x$ inputs needed to produce every single real number are ordered from smallest to largest? Basically, why is it the case here that the larger the $x$-value you put in, the larger the $y$-value?

Can someone please explain to me, as simply as possible and without calculus, why the range of the function is all real numbers? And furthermore, can you prove to me that the $x$ inputs needed to produce every single real number are ordered from smallest to largest? Basically, why is it the case here that the larger the $x$-value you put in, the larger the $y$-value?

Comment: @drhab That's what I meant sorry, I'll correct it.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Notice that the denominator gets very small as $x$ approaches either $1$ or $-1$, which allows the value of the function to become very large.

Comment: Yes, but what I'm asking is not if the function can produce very large numbers, but if the function can produce every single real number. And furthermore, can you prove to me that the x inputs needed to produce every single real number are ordered from smallest to largest? Why is it the case here that the larger the x-value you put in, the larger the y-value?

Comment: @EthanChan if $f(a)$ is very small and $f(b)$ then -because $f$ is continuous - the intermediate value theorem assures that $y=f(x)$ for some $x$ whenever $f(a)\leq y\leq f(b)$.

Comment: @drhab I'm sorry, but how do we know it's continuous. The intermediate value theorem doesn't mean anything to me, since I haven't learn it yet. And the wikipedia page I read about it doesn't give me a good explanation either; because it uses more theorems and symbols to justify it which I haven't learnt before. Can you give me a simpler explanation?

Comment: In that case (no knowledge of IVT and not knowing how to prove continuity) you can do it with the answer of gimusi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have that $f(x)\ge 0$ for $x\ge 0$ and $f(x)< 0$ for $x< 0$ and thus

$$y=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\implies y^2(1-x^2)=x^2\implies x^2(1+y^2)=y^2\implies x=\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}$$

which is defined for any $y\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, but fortunately it is not needed to find an inverse for this. That can be quite difficult.

Comment: @dehab I also would use the surjectivity argument but the OP is asking for a solution without calculus concepts.

Comment: Yes. A recent comment of the OP learned me now that your answer is the best for him/her after all.

Comment: The implication that your arrows claim is not the one that is needed.

Answer (score 2):

The function is defined on $(-1,1)$ and is continuous.

Then in order to show that $\mathbb R$ is its range it is enough to prove that there are sequences $(x_n)_n$ and $(y_n)_n$ in $(-1,1)$ such that $f(x_n)\to+\infty$ and $f(y_n)\to-\infty$.

For this you can take $x_n=1-\frac1n$ and $y_n=-x_n$.

The [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) then assures that for every $y\in\mathbb R$ we can find some $x\in(-1,1)$ that satisfies $y=f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, let $x$ be a real numer, if you choose $t=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ (which is different from $1$), then your function's value on $t$ is $x$. This can be done to any real number $x$, therefore the function's range is the set of all real numbers.

Comment: and of course with some calculus you can see how the function cover all the real numbers by producing large numbers from the denominater.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your function is defined and continuous on $]-1,1[$. Check where the function "starts" ($x\to -1$) and "ends" ($x\to 1$) and connect those "points" by a line, as you are allowed to do because your function is continuous.